Is it possible to convert a class with a constructor to functional component with same props defined?
I am newly started using matter-js and react-native-game-engine and trying to figure out why class definition is used. I observed such questions in stack but couldn't find the exactly similar answer. I am confused to migrate this part especially: this.entities = this.setupWorld();. My whole class definition is as follows:
import Matter from "matter-js";
import { GameEngine } from "react-native-game-engine";

export default class GameApp extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            running: true,
            score: 0,
        };

        this.gameEngine = null;

        this.entities = this.setupWorld();
    }

    setupWorld = () => {
        let engine = Matter.Engine.create({ enableSleeping: false });
        let world = engine.world;
        world.gravity.y = 0.0;

        let bird = Matter.Bodies.rectangle( Constants.MAX_WIDTH / 2, Constants.MAX_HEIGHT / 2, Constants.BIRD_WIDTH, Constants.BIRD_HEIGHT);

        let floor1 = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
            Constants.MAX_WIDTH / 2,
            Constants.MAX_HEIGHT - 25,
            Constants.MAX_WIDTH + 4,
            50,
            { isStatic: true }
        );

        let floor2 = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
            Constants.MAX_WIDTH + (Constants.MAX_WIDTH / 2),
            Constants.MAX_HEIGHT - 25,
            Constants.MAX_WIDTH + 4,
            50,
            { isStatic: true }
        );


        Matter.World.add(world, [bird, floor1, floor2]);
        Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', (event) => {
            var pairs = event.pairs;

            this.gameEngine.dispatch({ type: "game-over"});

        });

        return {
            physics: { engine: engine, world: world },
            floor1: { body: floor1, renderer: Floor },
            floor2: { body: floor2, renderer: Floor },
            bird: { body: bird, pose: 1, renderer: Bird},
        }
    }

    onEvent = (e) => {
        if (e.type === "game-over"){
            //Alert.alert("Game Over");
            this.setState({
                running: false
            });
        } else if (e.type === "score") {
            this.setState({
                score: this.state.score + 1
            })
        }
    }

    reset = () => {
        resetPipes();
        this.gameEngine.swap(this.setupWorld());
        this.setState({
            running: true,
            score: 0
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View ...
         )
    }
}

My outcome is something like this but there is problem about passing props I think:
export default GameApp = () =>  {
    const [running, setRunning] = useState(true)
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0)
    let gameEngine = null
    let entities = null

    useEffect(()=>{
        entities = setupWorld()
    },[])

    const setupWorld = () => {
        let engine = Matter.Engine.create({ enableSleeping: false });
        let world = engine.world;
        world.gravity.y = 0.0;

        let bird = Matter.Bodies.rectangle( Constants.MAX_WIDTH / 2, Constants.MAX_HEIGHT / 2, Constants.BIRD_WIDTH, Constants.BIRD_HEIGHT);

        let floor1 = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
            Constants.MAX_WIDTH / 2,
            Constants.MAX_HEIGHT - 25,
            Constants.MAX_WIDTH + 4,
            50,
            { isStatic: true }
        );

        let floor2 = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
            Constants.MAX_WIDTH + (Constants.MAX_WIDTH / 2),
            Constants.MAX_HEIGHT - 25,
            Constants.MAX_WIDTH + 4,
            50,
            { isStatic: true }
        );


        Matter.World.add(world, [bird, floor1, floor2]);
        Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', (event) => {
            var pairs = event.pairs;

            gameEngine.dispatch({ type: "game-over"});

        });

        return {
            physics: { engine: engine, world: world },
            floor1: { body: floor1, renderer: Floor },
            floor2: { body: floor2, renderer: Floor },
            bird: { body: bird, pose: 1, renderer: Bird},
        }
    }

    const onEvent = (e) => {
        if (e.type === "game-over"){
            setRunning(false)
        } else if (e.type === "score") {
            setScore(score+1)
        }
    }

    const reset = () => {
        resetPipes();
        gameEngine.swap(setupWorld());
        setRunning(true)
        setScore(0)
    }

        return (
            <View style={style
    ...

    )
    }

There is an error coming in this usage:
const Physics = (entities, { touches, time, dispatch }) => {
    let engine = entities.physics.engine;  // Cannot read property 'engine' of undefined 
let world = entities.physics.world;
let bird = entities.bird.body;

I tried passing them like this below but same error (cannot read 'engine' of undefined in Physics.js):
export default GameApp = (props) =>  {
    const [running, setRunning] = useState(true)
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0)
    let {gameEngine, entities} = props

Meanwhile, I am using this GameApp component as a screen in App.js like this:
function App() {
  ...
  return (
   <GameApp/>
  )
}

The reason why I am trying to migrate is to use the hooks.

Your engine came from your setupWorld function. It doesn't came from your props.
I think you should setup the engine in useMemo in GameApp and have another React.FC which will take engine as props.
interface ScreenWithMatherProps {
  engine: Matter.engine
}
const ScreenWithMather: React.FC = ({engine}) => {
  if(!engine){
    return null 
  }
   ...
   //All your code here will only execute when engine is ready
}


The error comes as I stated on edit

Javascript
With Javascript, you do not need to type the properties, you can past them ambiguously. Also, here you can see we deconstruct the properties.
export const FunctionalComponent = ({something, foo, bar}) =>{ ... }

/** Usages **/
<FunctionalComponent something={true} foo="hello" bar={[{id: 1, text: "some data"}]}/>

Typescript
Generally, it's best practice to not do implicit anys which is what javascript does. The example below provides an interface to the props, so it's hard-typed.
interface Props {
   something: boolean,
   foo: string,
   bar: {id: number, text: string}[],
   optionalThing?: string,
}

export const FunctionalComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => { ... }


The error comes as I stated on edit.

Yes, you are passing a non-constructed variable through props. Props are either constructed or not-constructed. in order for you to have both, it needs to be passed in as such: {destructure, ...otherprops}

 this is incorrect, it should be 

But they should be inside GameApp.js file, I cannot define engine from app.js and pass it as prop of GameApp.
